# {% block content %} not working in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I am learning about template inheritence in django

base.html:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>leshav</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My helpful timestamp site</h1>
    { % block content % }{ % endblock % }
    <footer>
        <hr>
        <p>thanks</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

dateTime.html:-

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <p>today is {{ d|date:'d-m-y' }}.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

view for the function related to this page's url:-

```
def current_datetime_block(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return render(request, "dateTime.html",{'d':now})
```

the problem is that it is not reading the content in the dateTime.html and is returning base.html file as it is

output:-

My helpful timestamp site

{ % block content % }{ % endblock % }

thanks

[This is the output when I run the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEKPG.png)

where the problem is coming? please help me
if anything else about the program is needed, you can ask me about it

Comment: `{ % block content % }{ % endblock % }` in base can not contain spaces between `{%` and `%}`

Comment: @DrummerMann thanks it worked, actually in book the font is in the way that gives the effect that there is a space